# Display a partial view containing a full calendar after click on link

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I have a problem with scripts and i think i don't understand correctly this part on the MVC. I installed the fullCalendar package because i need a calendar to select dates for many equipments. i would like to have an equipments list where each equipment will have a link to open a calendar to select dates on the same view. here is my code:

partial view containing the calendar: _PlanningEquipement.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <h2>Planning Equipement</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 offset-1">
            <div id='calendar'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <hr />

    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
        <h5>Réservation</h5>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <!--Date picker -->
                <div class="input-group date">
                    @Html.Label("Date Début: ")
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NomZone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-5", @id = "datepickerdebut", @placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" } })
                    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepickerdebut" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.NomZone, "Matin")
                @Html.Label("Matin", new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.NomZone, "Après-midi")
                @Html.Label("Après-midi", new { @class = "col-md-8 control-label" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    @Html.Label("Date Fin: ")
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NomZone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-5", @id = "datepickerfin", @placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" } })
                    <!-- CHANGER LE m => m.NomZone et rajouter la vrai variable du viewModel<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepickerdebut" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Zones, "Matin")
                @Html.Label("Matin", new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Zones, "Après-midi")
                @Html.Label("Après-midi", new { @class = "col-md-8 control-label" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <span class="fas fa-plus-circle" style="color:green"></span>
        <!-- îcone à cliquer pour rajouter des créneaux réservation -->
    </div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.css">
```

EquipementVsZone (here i have the list with equipments where each equipment have a link to open their own calendar) :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EquipementVsZone";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<hr />
<h5>Liste des équipements pour la zone @Model.NomZone </h5>
<br />

<div class="form-group">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("TrouverProjet", "Reservation", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Equipements.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Equipements[i].EstSelectionne)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Equipements[i].EstSelectionne, Model.Equipements[i].equipement.nom + "( Num GMAO: " + Model.Equipements[i].equipement.numGmao + " )")
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            Emplacement pour la photo
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            Emplacement pour les liens résa!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    @*@Html.ActionLink("Voir Disponibilité", "PlanningEquipement", "Reservation", new { id = Model.Equipements[i].equipement.id }, new { @class = "btn-link" })*@
                    <a class="btn-link" href="#" onclick="showCalendar(@Model.Equipements[i].equipement.id)">Voir disponibilité</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7 offset-2" id="planning">
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <br />
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <!--'javascript:history.go(-1)' pour revenir à la page précedente :) pas mal! voir pour le rajouter sur
                    le formulaire projet et vérifier si le récapitulatif se met à jour-->
                <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                    Annuler
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-9 col-md-1">
                <input type="submit" value="Valider" class="btn btn-default navbar-inra" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }

</div>

@section Scripts
{
    @*<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.dispo').click(function () {
                    $("#planning").load('@Url.Content("~/Areas/Reservation/Views/Shared/_PlanningEquipement.cshtml")');
                });
        });
        </script>*@
    <!-- JS includes -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Datepicker moment with locales -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="datetimepicker/js/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

    <!-- Propeller Bootstrap datetimepicker -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showCalendar(parameter) {
            $("#planning").load('@Url.Content("~/Areas/Reservation/Views/Shared/_PlanningEquipement.cshtml")');
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#planning').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 300,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                firstDay: 1, //The day that each week begins (Monday=1)
                slotMinutes: 60,
                events: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetEvents", controller="Home"})'
            });
            $('#datepickerdebut').datepicker();
            $('#datepickerfin').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
}
```

This is what i will like to open for each equipment:
[image]

instead i have this and without clicking on the link:
[image]

Can someone help me please? :) thanks in advance

Comment: Just a guess here, but are you missing a `css` file on that page?

Comment: i add the link to the css file on the partial view "_PlanningEsquipement.cshtml, i don't know it is correct